# Программно скрыть расширенный AppBarLayout

Tags: android, toolbar

Мне нужно при входе в фрагмент свернуть `AppBarLayout`, так что бы показовался только `toolbar`
Мой `xml` :

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_home_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_home_toolbar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/activity_home_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Сейчас по дефолту такой всегда `toolbar`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137264/3212712):

> Using support libs v23 you can call appBarLayout.setExpanded(true/false)

С последней версией библиотеки можно программно "схлопнуть"/"развернуть" `CollapsingToolbarLayout` методом `setExpanded(boolean expand)` класса `AppBarLayout`

```
//схлопнуть
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false); //или развернуть appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
```

@pavlofff добавляет:

> так же есть альтернативный методу `setExpanded()` `XML`-атрибут: `app:expanded="false"` для установки параметра "на старте"

Comment: так же есть альтернативный методу `setExpanded()` XML-атрибут: `app:expanded="false"` для установки параметра "на старте"

Comment: @pavlofff, спс, добавил в ответ. Кстати, забавно, как на слух звучит название символа `@` вместе с вашим ником)))